# Can not upload new .obb to google play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

This happened today. The dropdown field for uploading a new obb is simply grayed out and I cant select it. [image].

Why and how does this happen and what should I do ?

Comment: I've had this happen when I forgot to upload an expansion file at first try. The only solution I've found is to submit a "new" build entirely.

Comment: @Bart what do you mean by a new build entirely ? Delete the whole app ?

Comment: No, a new version code.

Comment: @Bart , the new version code did not solve the issue the filed is still grey.

Comment: Update: Closing the tab with the console and opening it again seemed to fix the issue. No idea why .

Comment: ... well, glad it's solved. The whole thing is a bit flaky every now and then.